# Ubuntu 22.04 apache2 won't start

Tags: apache2, 22.04

Fresh install on a new computer (dell xps 13 plus) with ubuntu 22.04

systemctl start apache2

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xeu apache2.service" for details.
```

systemctl status apache2.service

```
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 apachectl[21340]: [Wed Nov 09 21:41:49.267432 2022] 

[so:warn] [pid 21340] AH01574: module php7_module is already loaded, skipping
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 apachectl[21340]: [Wed Nov 09 21:41:49.267439 2022] [so:warn] [pid 21340] AH01574: module reqtimeout_module is already loaded, skipping
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 apachectl[21340]: [Wed Nov 09 21:41:49.267446 2022] [so:warn] [pid 21340] AH01574: module setenvif_module is already loaded, skipping
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 apachectl[21340]: [Wed Nov 09 21:41:49.267453 2022] [so:warn] [pid 21340] AH01574: module status_module is already loaded, skipping
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 apachectl[21340]: apache2: Syntax error on line 261 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 256 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2>
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 apachectl[21337]: Action 'start' failed.
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 apachectl[21337]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 09 21:41:49 seb-XPS-9320 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

this is the code I have at line 261 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

this is the code I have at line 256 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/apache2.conf

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

what's wrong with these lines?

Comment: Looks like the issue is with one of the `.conf` files being loaded from within `sites-enabled`, and line 2 specifically 

Comment: I'm afraid that it is a loop inclusion, you load in loop all *.conf file from site-enabled folder. In the site-enabled folder should have only *.conf with virtualHost which are symlink from sites-available folder created by a2ensite "sitename".